# Create a plugin with class library that contains an html,css file

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, plugins

i want to make an plugin that contains a simple html button or label to later use on my ASP.NET website. Any tips on how to do this?

And i guess this class library can be made into a DLL that can be used. Is this also possible if there are HTML,CSS files included?

Comment: If you put the css and html in a sting variable that you can access in the library and print those on the actual html page then it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the build action property of your files ( such as HTML, CSS, Js, Image,...) as "Embedded resource".